# Debian or CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, debian

I am looking at using either Debian or CentOS for a production server and I've heard mixed reviews of each one.

I've heard CentOS performs better under load, however I am aware that Debian has a much larger package repository.

Personally, I am partial to Debian since I am less familiar with Red Hat distros, but wanted to reach out on Server Fault to see which I really should be using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end, you're the one that has to secure it. As such, the one you know how to secure properly is the best choice.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a Debian man, so the below may be slightly biased towards Debian.

They'll both perform the same and when you compare CentOS + EPEL with Debian + Backports, the package repositories are about as diverse as each other.

Debian has a slightly shorter release cycle, so you'll get newer packages more often.  It's really down to your personal choice.  If you're more comfortable with Debian, then go with Debian.